# Higher order Legendre's linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, legendre-polynomials

I understand that a Legendre's linear equation has the following form:

$a_n (\alpha x + \beta) \frac{d^n y}{dx^n} +....+ a_1(\alpha x + \beta)\frac{dy}{dx} + a_0 y = f(x) $

where $\alpha, \beta$ and $a_n$ are constant terms. In order to solve this kind of equation my textbook suggests the following substitution:
$ \alpha x + \beta = e^t$

$\therefore \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dt}{dx} \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha x + \beta} \frac{dy}{dt}$

And then it suggests looking at the higher order derivatives, for example for order 2:

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{dy}{dx} = (\frac{\alpha}{\alpha x + \beta})^2 (\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} - \frac{dy}{dt} )$

However how is this possible? Shouldn't it be:

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{dy}{dx} = (\frac{\alpha}{\alpha x + \beta})^2 \frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{d^2y}{dt dx} (\frac{\alpha}{\alpha x + \beta})$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}&=\frac{d}{dx} \frac{dy}{dx}\\
& =  \frac{d}{dx}\Bigl(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha x + \beta}\,\frac{dy}{dt}\Bigr)\\
&=-\bigl(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha x + \beta}\Bigr)^2 \frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{\alpha}{\alpha x + \beta}\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dy}{dt}\\
&=-\bigl(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha x + \beta}\Bigr)^2 \frac{dy}{dt} +\bigl(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha x + \beta}\Bigr)^2 \frac{d^2
y}{dt^2}\ .
\end{align}

Comment: Why is $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha x + \beta}\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dy}{dt}$ equal to $\bigl(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha x + \beta}\Bigr)^2 \frac{d^2
y}{dt^2}\ $?

Comment: Because for any function $f$ $$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha x + \beta}\,\frac{df}{dt}.$$ Now let $f=dy/dt$,

Comment: Hmm, could you please explain why is that the case or provide a reference for that claim? I cannot seem to find anything about that assumption on my textbook.

Comment: It is the first formula in your question.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense